# Label drawing not showing in form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to add 2 label at the same group box, this is my code :

```
        int x = 0;
        foreach (var item in comboboxinterface.Items)
        {
            drv = item as DataRowView;
            Button btn = new Button();
            Label lblerrortoday = new Label();
            Label lblcounterror = new Label();
            btn.Text = drv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 20 + (x * 30));
            lblcounterror.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(100, 25 + (x * 30));
            lblcounterror.Text = "No";
            lblerrortoday.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(120, 25 + (x * 30));
            lblerrortoday.Text = "Error Today";
            grouptodayerror.Controls.Add(btn);
            grouptodayerror.Controls.Add(lblcounterror);
            grouptodayerror.Controls.Add(lblerrortoday);
            x++;
        }
```

But when i start the program, the `lblerrortoday` is not showing up but the `lblcountererror` is fine, when i tried to comment the the `lblcounterror`, the `lblerrortoday` is showing fine, did i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your approach seems to ok, only point to note that width of labels that may cause for not displaying other label.

You could use  <kbd>[Control.AutoSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.autosize(v=vs.110).aspx)</kbd> property , This may resolve your problem

```
lblcounterror.AutoSize = true;
lblerrortoday.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @JaydipJ, it's working now, noted :)

Answer (score 1):

The `TextBox` is there, but overlapped by `lblcounterror`. Reduce `Width` of `lblcounterror` and you will see `lblerrortoday`.